# how to autoincrement varchar datatype depending upon the product details name using trigger

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, trigger

I have a **product details table**, the fields in the table are *Prod_Id, Product_Name, Quantity, Slno*. Now i have created trigger for varchar data type field and implemented auto increment for Prod_Id (Primary key) and for Slno. The output will be

**Prod_Id -->>>  PROD0001, PROD0002** and so on. Now if the product name is RACK it should create a id RACK_001 with the start two letters of the product name and auto increment automatically.  For all Product name it should create accordingly,how to do this.

As of now i am using a trigger for auto increment  in varchar data type. Help with the trigger code.

```
DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER tg_product_details_INSERT
  BEFORE INSERT ON product_details
  FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO product_details_seq VALUES (NULL);
     SET NEW.Created_Date = NOW();
     SET NEW.Submitted_Date = NOW();
     SET NEW.Slno = coalesce((select max(Slno) from product_details), 0) + 1;
     SET NEW.Prod_id = CONCAT((NEW.Prefix), LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
   END
DELIMITER ;
```

product name -->> BOOK, SHOE, DRESS, FURNITURE

for all book it should create a autoincrement id BOOK_001, BOOK_002  and for all Shoe it should create a autoincrement id like SHOE_001, SHOE_002  and so on...!!!

Thanks,
Acube.

Comment: Are you aware that the `select max(Slno) from product_details` subquery will cause all your inserts to serialize? This is usually a terrible idea, which is why most RDBMSs provide some sort of [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html) feature

Comment: Use [two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7344648/533832)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
SET NEW.Prod_id = CONCAT('PROD', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
SET NEW.Prod_id = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(NEW.Product_Name,1,2), NEW.Prod_id);
```

Thanks
Acube.

Answer (score 2):

- Store the "BO" and "1" as two columns.
- INDEX that pair of columns so that you can find the max
- Construct 'BO_002' when fetching the row by doing `CONCAT(prefix, '_', seq)`.  (And use `ZEROFILL` instead of `LPAD`, etc).